# Should I add .idea/assetWizardSettings.xml to gitignore?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, gitignore

Should I add .idea/assetWizardSettings into git ignore? It is generated when I created launcher icons for adaptive and legacy

Comment: put the entire directory `.idea/` into gitignore

Comment: @Mavamaarten depends on project requirements tbh. `.idea/` is definitely beneficial. You can have copyright templates too for the source files in there. But again, depends on project requirements.

Answer (score 10):

You can add it to your `.gitignore` file and your project will be fine.
The `.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml` is just a file that contains the configuration settings the Image Asset Studio used to create your icon.

Comment: Thank You Marco :)

Answer (score 5):

All the build related files are generated better not to add these files into git, Adding them to gitignore is the best option.